# After upgrading to React Native 0.60 , getting error "Undefined is not an object " '_reactNative.NetInfo.getConnectionInfo'

Tags: react-native

I have recently upgraded to react-native version **0.60** from **0.57.8**. I have successfully completed the upgrade. But got stuck in this error. 
   I came to know that "NetInfo" has been extracted from the react-native core. So, I have removed the code temporarily and the libraries which were using NetInfo. But still i am not able to remove this bug. Looking for some help.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly as you imported NetInfo in React-native Remove it and
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image,**NetInfo**  } from 'react-native';
 and use new it import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

then install this plugin npm install --save @react-native-community/netinfo.

Comment: I am using Aws AppSync in my application . I am not sure but after digging deeper, i found that this library uses "_reactNative.NetInfo.getConnectionInfo". I have contacted the Aws Support team.

Comment: Adding to the context of author's comment above, just upgrade to `aws-appsync@^2.0.0` or above should solve the problem.